# Print current and next element in a list, but in reverse order

Tags: python, list

Given a `lst = ["one", "two", "three"]` I would like to print current and its next element, but in reverse order. That is:

```
three one
two three
one two
```

my script prints current and next element, but not in reverse order:

```
# It prints:
# one two
# two three
for curr, nxt in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
    print(curr, nxt)
```

- How can I edit my script so that I achieve my goal?

I tried the following:

```
# It prints:
# three one
for curr, nxt in zip(lst[-1:], lst):
   print(curr, nxt)
```

but it only gives me one result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `zip` is not the solution I would go for here, as you would need to concatenate two arrays in order to get the circularly shifted array (slice alone cannot shift circularly). What I would do however is simply run over all of the elements in the reversed list, and get the next value by it's index, like so:

```py
list = ["one", "two", "three"]

for i, curr in enumerate(list[::-1]): # enumerate gives you a generator of (index, value)
   nxt = list[-i] # list[-i-1] would be the current value, so -i would be the next one
   print(curr, nxt)
```

**Edit:**
Using `list[::-1]` is slightly slower than you would normally want it, because it would go over the list once to reverse it, and then another time to iterate over it. A better solution would be:

```py
list = ["one", "two", "three"]

for i in range(len(list)-1, -1, -1):
    curr = list[i]
    nxt = list[len(list) - i - 1] # list[i+1] would not work as it would be index out of range, but this way it overflows to the negative side, which python allows.
    print(curr, nxt)
```

If you do however wish to use `zip`, you would need to do this:

```py
list = ["one", "two", "three"]

for curr, nxt in zip(list[::-1], [list[0]] + list[:0:-1]):
    print(curr, nxt)
```

You should also note that naming your variable `list` is not a good idea as you would then shadow python's built in [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) method, you should probably name it `lst` or something similar to that.

Comment: I think this is the most straightforward solution

Comment: @tail It's also broken as it shadows the *list* built-in. It's also the most time consuming. Look at the answer from ThePyGuy for a better solution

Comment: @Vlad you are right, using `list[::-1]` was just laziness. I have updated my answer to now also include a better solution. Also regarding the shadowing of `list`, this is also correct, but the list in the question is called `list`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the reversed index which will point you to the current item, and you can take modulo of the index by length of the list, which will point you to the next item

```py
for i in range(len(lst), 0, -1):
    print(lst[i-1], lst[i%len(lst)])
  
# output:  
three one
two three
one two
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, the `%` operator will be helpful to find the next element if index exceeds `size of list - 1`.

- Loop from index `size-1` to `0`
- The next element is simply `i+1`. However to deal with the case where `i+1` exceeds boundaries of the list, we can use `(i+1)%size` to "restart index".

```py
lst = ["one", "two", "three"]
size= len(lst)

# loop starting at index (size-1) and ending at index  0
for i in range(size-1,-1,-1): 
    currentElement = lst[i]
    nextElement = lst[(i+1)%size] 
    print(currentElement, nextElement)
```

Output :

```
three one
two three
one two
```

Comment: Do not use *list* and *next* as variables as you'll shadow the built-ins

Comment: @Vlad Thanks for the feedback. I fixed my mistake. Hope the variable names are alright now.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want this..

```py
a = ["one", "two", "three"] 
a.append(a[0])
a.reverse()

for curr, nxt in zip(a, a[1:]):
    print(nxt, curr)
```

Also it is strongly recommended to avoid using keywords `list` as variable names.

Comment: It's also a good idea not to use *next*

Comment: @Vlad You're right, I was negligent

Comment: This modifies the original list - not a good idea. Perhaps take a copy first

Comment: I understand the side effects of doing this in practice, but I just wish it was more relevant to the original question